# Unzip many files to a given directory

Tags: linux

In short, i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, but basically what i want to do is loop over all zip files, and unzip their content for a directory with the name of the zip.

example:

Files: `a.zip`, `b.zip`

Command

```
for i in `ls *.zip`; do unzip $i -d  `echo $i | cut -f1 -d'.'` ; done
```

expected:

Folder `a` with content of `a.zip`
folder `b` with content of `b.zip`

What is happening:

> No zipfiles found.
>   unzip:  cannot find or open a.zip, a.zip.zip or a.zip.ZIP.

Any tip on what's could be possibly wrong?

Comment: Did you check the read permissions on those zip files?

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29248777/180100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `find` without parsing the output of ls or of `find` itself in order to avoid some problems essentially related with [special characters eventually present in the filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

```
 find . -name "*.zip" -exec bash -c ' unzip "$0" -d "${0%*.zip}"  '  {} \;
```

Comment: As suggested in a disappeared answer, **without the need of creating a directory for each file** it should be done with **`unzip '*zip'`**. Note the quote `'`. If the zip files were created with  something similar to `zip -r myfolder.zip myfolder/` the simple unzip command will recreate the directory structure. BTW In this case It works fine even with the double quote **`unzip "*zip"`** or escaping the `*` with **`unzip \*zip`**.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
for i in *.zip; do
newdir="${i:0:-4}" && mkdir "$newdir"
unzip "$i" -d  "$newdir"
done
```

Comment: ...and it will until all your file names will be **without special characters or spaces** else it will generate error and exit with error code (`echo $?`) 1. In general is not suggested [to parse the output of ls](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: yeah, `ls` isn't recommended here, I used it because I just edited OP's original post. omitted `ls` now

Comment: With quotes (as `"$i"`) it should hold for space and newlines. Remember to add quote `"` to deal with those problems. (Check it with e.g. `cp c.zip a$'\n'b.zip` It will create a file with a newline between `a` and `b.zip` if the file `c.zip` exists).

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
for i in `find | grep .zip$`;do unzip $i;done
```

EDIT

Previous answer is wrong (;

```
for i in `find | grep .zip$ | sed 's@.zip$@@'`;do mkdir $i;unzip $i.zip -d $i;done
```

Try this one!

Comment: That won't extract the content for a specified directory :)

Comment: Yeah, missed that part (; I'm fixing my answer now

Comment: Ok, i'm cooking your accept point meanwhile.

Comment: It's blunt, granted, but should work nevertheless, if a more elegant answer arrives, feel free to accept it

Comment: Unfortunately both example will fail with filenames with spaces or newlines.